# Alignment of Paragraph/Wrapfigure/Minipage

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage, wrapfigure

I'm not that used to writing more complex and visually appealing Latex Documents.
I'm trying to vertically align a minipage containing a paragraph with a wrapfigure. Each image corresponds to a paragraph on the left. In the Screenshot you can notice the misalignment. Below you find the sample code of the first paragraph. The other ones are basically the same.

Thanks in Advance!

```
\begin{wrapfigure}[13]{rt}{0.3\textwidth}
\hspace{0.05\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{example-image} 
\caption{Polykristallines Dickschicht PV-Modul (Quelle)}
\label{Fig_PolykristallineDickschicht PV-Modul}
\end{wrapfigure} 

\begin{minipage}[c]{0.59\textwidth}
    \paragraph*{Polykristalline Dickschicht PV-Module} 
    Polykristalline PV-Module hingegen sind inhomogener und bestehen aus vielen einzelnen Siliziumkristallen. 
    Dafür werden im Bridgeman Verfahren Silizium in Tiegelform erhitzt und erstarren im Anschluss, wodurch eine Kristallisation stattfindet.
    Die abgekühlten Tiegel werden im Anschluss ebenfalls in dünne Scheiben (Wafern) geschnitten.
\end{minipage}
```

[image: Screenshot of PDF]

Comment: wrapfigure is designed to make the following paragraph have modified line lengths so that it "wraps" around the figure, minipage is a large rectangular block that acts like a single character paragraph so defeats all of wrapfig's actions,

Comment: okay I Understand. How would you recomend to proceed to reach the desired outcome

Answer (score 0):

- You should provide MWE (Minimal Working Example). Due to lack of it your question is a bit unclear.
- Using standard `article` documentclass and `[ngerman]{babel}` for hyphenation of German words, the MWE canbe:

```
\documentclass{article}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                              % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}[13]{rt}{0.3\textwidth}
\hspace{0.05\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{Polykristallines Dickschicht PV-Modul (Quelle)}
\label{Fig_PolykristallineDickschicht PV-Modul}
\end{wrapfigure}
\paragraph*{Polykristalline Dickschicht PV-Module}
    Polykristalline PV-Module hingegen sind inhomogener und bestehen aus vielen einzelnen Siliziumkristallen.
    Dafür werden im Bridgeman Verfahren Silizium in Tiegelform erhitzt und erstarren im Anschluss, wodurch eine Kristallisation stattfindet.
    Die abgekühlten Tiegel werden im Anschluss ebenfalls in dünne Scheiben (Wafern) geschnitten.
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

As you can see, in above MWE are dropout all `minipage`s. They are superfluous.

Is this what you after?